# Transfer Bluetooth LE profile between partitions

Tags: windows, macos, bluetooth

I'm trying to use a Bluetooth LE mouse (Microsoft Mouse 3600) in a Bootcamp installation without having to re-pair it every time I log into Windows or macOS. I have read that the process essentially consists of both computers having the same Bluetooth MAC address (this shouldn't be a problem) and copying the link-key of the mouse connection from macOS to Windows. In practice, this doesn't apply to Bluetooth LE devices because, up to my understanding, they have a different pairing procedure, and are stored differently. Also, these devices change their unique id every time they are paired as well as the link-key, and probably more data I don't know about as well.

I thought on copying the entire Bluetooth profile and recreating it at registry level, but changing the unique id of the device will surely bring problems for the connection and will not update the Bluetooth profile (seen in the windows control panel, in view devices and printers). So what would be the best way to copy the Bluetooth profile? Or what would be an alternative, clean, way to solve this?

Thanks